# How to check what git rebase had changed?

Tags: git, rebase, git-history-rewrite

Is there a way to check what `git rebase` had changed after doing the rebase and exiting rebase mode?

I used rebase to change the author name of previous commits.

While trying to do so, I rebased in wrong branch (i.e., `master`) which viewed to me in the rebase file some commits that were not my target. Therefore, I just quit the editor and it said "Rebase done successfully".

At the end, I switched to my local branch (i.e., `vIO`) and I could change the author name but I want to check that my other rebasing trials didn't affect the history. BTW, my local branch (`vIO`) is not yet pushed to remote.

I tried comparing local master to remote master by:

`git diff origin/master...master`

This didn't bring anything. Does this mean for sure that the master branch was not affected by the rebasing?

Comment: Your question is a bit broad, but actually during the rebase you can get already get a glimpse into what is happening.  What exactly do you want to know?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`git` keeps a log for each separate branch, which you can access through the `git reflog` command :

- `git reflog master` will show you the evolution of your local `master` branch,
- `git reflog vIO` the evolution of your local `vIO` branch.

In this reflog, actions that were applied by a rebase will appear with a message :

```
rebase (finish): refs/heads/branchname onto eacf32bb...
```

---

The `git diff origin/master...master` command told you that there was no new content on master, which is a good indication.

If you want to be 100% sure `master` didn't move, look at the list of commits with `git log` :

```
git log --graph --oneline origin/master master
```

will allow you to see if there are any different commits the two branches :

- if the labels `master` and `origin/master` appear on the same commit, the two branches are in sync ;
- otherwise, look at the graph to understand what action should be taken (`pull`, `push`, `merge`, `rebase` ...)

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks so much. Could you please explain the last command in more details? I run it and it shawed me all the commits in the master branch. So I don't know if it should shaw the difference between the local and remote branches in a different color or by distinguishing it explicitly?